# QueryString not executed from javascript set in bottom

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Actually I have a javascript class where I call a QueryString, the js file is included in the bottom of aspx file and it works fine when the js is included on the HEAD but the issue is if I include it in head some javascript functions will not be executed in the site.

[image]

Here is an example from a bootstrap table i get row id and pass it to the querystring then i'm trying to show the bootstrap modal with info selected from db for that id

```
function openModal(id) {
    window.location.href = "admin_assistenza.aspx?MODAL=" + id
}
```

While on load of the codebehind i set the following code to show a bootstrap modal with items from the id passed to it

This is the code set in Page Load

```
ElseIf Request.QueryString("MODAL") <> "" Then
                MoreInfo(Request.QueryString("MODAL"))
            End If
```

While here is the moreInfo function

```
   Sub MoreInfo(ByVal id As String)
        GetImage(id)
        con.Open()
        Dim msd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT oggetto_ti, desc_ti FROM ticket WHERE id=" & id, con)

        reader = msd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()

            lblModalTitle.Text = reader.GetString("oggetto_ti")
            lblModalBody.Text = reader.GetString("desc_ti")
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#exampleModal').modal();", True)
            upModal.Update()

        End While


        placeholderTicket.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(table.ToString))

        reader.Close()

        con.Close()


    End Sub
```

Comment: You really need to show some code, and why you refer to Java (a completely different programming language and platform to JavaScript and to .NET).

Comment: @Richard just added the code

Comment: Perhaps this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648025/asp-net-repeater-with-bootstrap-3-modal-confirmation-on-delete/54267357#54267357